# Stored procedure Item Reader version in Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I want to know in which version of Spring Batch StoredProcedureItemReader class was introduced. I checked quite a lot but not finding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `StoredProcedureItemReader` was introduced as the result of Spring Batch issue BATCH-729 (https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-729) which has a fix version of 2.1.0.RC1.